# define DTO for ApiParam and ApiQuery

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I'm using the [nestjs swagger module](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) and want to create my API documentation. For endpoints relying on the request body I can assign a DTO class to the docs like

```
@ApiBody({ type: CreateUserDTO })
```

Some endpoints also rely on the request params or queries. For params I would do something like

```
@ApiParam({ type: GetUserByIdDTO })
```

(I know this is a bad example because there is no need for a DTO for a user id but let's assume you want to validate your params with a DTO class using class-validator)

but I'm getting this error

> Argument of type '{ type: typeof GetUserByIdDTO; }' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'ApiParamOptions'.   Property 'name' is missing
>   in type '{ type: typeof GetUserByIdDTO; }' but required in type
>   'ApiParamMetadata'.

For queries I would do something like

```
@ApiQuery({ type: GetUsersDTO })
```

and get this error

> Argument of type '{ type: typeof GetUsersDTO; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ApiQueryOptions'.   Property 'name' is missing in
>   type '{ type: typeof GetUsersDTO; }' but required in type
>   'ApiQueryMetadata'.

So the `APIBody` decorator seems to work fine but how can I fix my `APIParam` and `APIQuery` decorators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@ApiQuery` and `@ApiParam` are needed when working with named params / query, like `@Query('pageSize')` o `@Param('id')`. In this case NestJS Swagger module should extract information *directly* from the DTO object specified, like:

```
async findElements(@Query() query: ElementsQueryDto) {
  // ...
}
```

An important thing to note is that Dtos should be classes, not interfaces.

Comment: I documented my dto fields with the `ApiProperty` decorator. And yes, this seems to be enough. So you say there is no need for the `ApiQuery` or `ApiParam` decoratior because this code is fine `public getUsers(@Query() getUsersDTO: GetUsersDTO): Promise<User[]> {
  /* ... */
}` because the swagger module will document the fields from the dto on its own?

Comment: Exactly, this is swagger nestjs module default behaviour and ApiQuery or ApiParam is intended as a fallback / shortand for simpler scenarios where you don’t need a Dto.